# Flask-WTForms: how to check if a field is required?

Tags: python, templates, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I defined a form in the following way:

```
class LoginForm(Form):
    login = EmailField(u'Email address', [required(), length(min=5, max=2048), validators.Email()])
    password = PasswordField(u'Password', [required(), length(min=6, max=50)])
    next = HiddenField()
    remember = BooleanField('Remember me')
    submit = SubmitField('Login')
```

Then I'm writing a generic macro in Jinja2 to render the form fields and I would like to do something like:

```
{% if field.is_required() %}
  {{ field.label(class_='required') }}
{% else %}
  {{ field.label() }}
{% endif %}
```

So... is there a way to see if a field is required?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Validators can [set flags](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6.1/validators.html#setting-flags-on-the-field-with-validators) which you can check for:

```
{% if field.flags.required %}field.label(class_='required'){% endif %}
```